# take filtered rows in count in navigation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to take in count filtered rows from an html table when I navigate it. I can't find any clear solutions, what would be the best way to do this please ?

Here is the filtering part of the script:

```js
function searchPokemon() {
    
            var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
            input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("pokemons-list");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    
                for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            
                    if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                
                if (found) {
            
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                    found = false;
                } else {
            
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

And here the table navigation part:

```js
var rows = document.getElementById("pokemons-list").children[1].children;
        var selectedRow = 0;
        
        document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
    
            rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";

            if(e.keyCode == 38){
                selectedRow--;
            } else if(e.keyCode == 40){
                selectedRow++;
            } else if(e.keyCode == 13){
                Pokemon_ID = selectedRow + 1;
                alert('Pokemon_ID = ' + Pokemon_ID);
            }
            if(selectedRow >= rows.length){
                selectedRow = 0;
            } else if(selectedRow < 0){
                selectedRow = rows.length-1;
            }
            
            rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";

            rows[selectedRow].scrollIntoView(true);
        
        };
```

Comment: still need help with this?

Comment: @Esaith Yes: I tried with a while loop (increment/decrement until reach visible element) but I need to press 2 times keyboard arrows to navigate search results and after navigating a bit the navigation stops working (I think this is because of the loop repeating infinite because I get a selectedRow undefined error, so I tried to break it when it reaches visible element but it didnt’t work)

Comment: Can you post a small snippet of the HTML, or is this dynamically created? If it is dynamically created, can you open up your dev tools in your browser, copy and paste the html on that page?

Comment: @Esaith Thank you! The table is generated by php (it is listing database table data). The table contain a serie of <tr> like this repeating for each database rows : <table id="pokemons-list">
                  <thead>
              
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><td>1</td><td>Bulbasaur</td><td><img src=""></td></tr>

Comment: Everything works fine now thanks to while loops, except that I have to press the keyboard arrows 2 times to select the next row in filtered list. What is causing this & how can I fix this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below snippet is a basic example of what you're trying to do. Run the code snippet and type 'Aa' (without the quotes). Notice when you press the down arrow you immediately get the first Aa but then have to press down 3 more times before the following line gets highlighted. The following two down arrows are really on the hidden tr elements. The elements are hidden from being show to the user but they are still within the DOM itself.

Solution: 
During the onkeydown event, before you change the background color to dodgerblue, verify the current tr element does not have display none. If it does, loop through again and check the next expected result. Since you have it looping through, as long as you don't loop back to beyond where you started then you shoudn't have an infinite loop.

```js
var searchPokemon;
var rows = document.getElementById("pokemons-list").children[1].children;
var selectedRow = 0;

document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {  
  rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
  
  if(e.keyCode == 38){
    selectedRow--;
  } else if(e.keyCode == 40){
    selectedRow++;
  } else if(e.keyCode == 13){
    Pokemon_ID = selectedRow + 1;
    alert('Pokemon_ID = ' + Pokemon_ID);
  }
  
  if(selectedRow >= rows.length){
    selectedRow = 0;
  } else if(selectedRow < 0){
    selectedRow = rows.length-1;
  }
  
  rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";
  
  rows[selectedRow].scrollIntoView(true);
  
};
        
        searchPokemon = function() {
    
            var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
            input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("pokemons-list");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    
                for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            
                    if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                
                if (found) {
            
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                    found = false;
                } else {
            
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="mySearch" />
<button type="button" onclick="searchPokemon()">Filter</button>
<table id="pokemons-list"> 
 <thead> </thead> 
 <tbody> 
  <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Aaa</td><td>
   <img src=""></td>
  </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Aba</td><td>
   <img src=""></td>
  </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Abb</td><td>
   <img src=""></td>
  </tr>
     <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   <td>4</td>
   <td>Aab</td><td>
   <img src=""></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The snippet below should be updated so allow you to do the same test, but skip the hidden tr elements.

```js
var searchPokemon;
var rows = document.getElementById("pokemons-list").children[1].children;
var selectedRow = 0;

document.body.onkeydown = function (e) {
 rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";

 var startedAt;

 do {
  startedAt = selectedRow;
  
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
   selectedRow--;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
   selectedRow++;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   Pokemon_ID = selectedRow + 1;
   alert('Pokemon_ID = ' + Pokemon_ID);
  }

  if (selectedRow >= rows.length) {
   selectedRow = 0;
  } else if (selectedRow < 0) {
   selectedRow = rows.length - 1;
  }
  
 } while (startedAt != selectedRow && rows[selectedRow].style.display === 'none');

 rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";
};

searchPokemon = function () {
 var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
 input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 table = document.getElementById("pokemons-list");
 tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

  for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
   if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    found = true;
   }
  }

  if (found) {
   tr[i].style.display = "";
   found = false;
  } else {
   tr[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="mySearch" />
<button type="button" onclick="searchPokemon()">Filter</button>
<table id="pokemons-list"> 
 <thead> </thead> 
 <tbody> 
  <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Aaa</td><td>
   <img src=""></td>
  </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Aba</td><td>
   <img src=""></td>
  </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Abb</td><td>
   <img src=""></td>
  </tr>
     <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
   <td>4</td>
   <td>Aab</td><td>
   <img src=""></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may want to add additional code to check if there are any items to loop through after you've filtered. Otherwise you may get unexpected results